jQuery Loop Through Data in Select Statement and Have Saved Option PreSelected
I have this admin page that lists a group of different cars where the administrator can come and click on an edit button and update one of the cars. When this happens the car is brought up in a form in a modal where changes can be made. The form has a save and cancel button in the modal.
Various things can be updated are typical car things like year, make, model, trim level, color, year, etc. So for example, one of the things that can be updated about the item is color, and a Select Statement with the colors offered for that model are listed. The Select is populated by a SQL Query.
The question: How do I have the vehicle color that is already saved, pre-Selected in the form element in the modal? Like the color of this particular car in the list was listed as TorRed and it should be Octane Red instead and the Administrator wants to update this particular cars color.
It's in Data Tables using jQuery, the middleware is Coldfusion, & the data is stored in a SQL Server database.
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o edit-button" aria-hidden="true" title="Edit Car" data-carid="#CarID#" data-carmake="#CarMake#" data-carmodel="#CarModel#" data-trimlevel="#TrimLevel# data-year="#Year#" data-colorname="#ColorName#" data-colorid="#ColorID#" data-isactive="#isActive#"></i>


$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            const modalForm = document.querySelector('#ModalForm');
            $('#CarID').val('');
            modalForm.reset();                
        });
        loadData();

        $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
            $('#CarMake').focus();
        })

        $('#data_grid_display').on('click', '.edit-button', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const ColorID = $(this).data('colorid');
            const ColorName = $(this).data('colorname');
            const isActive = $(this).data('isactive');
            $('#ColorID').val(ColorID);
            $('#ColorName').val(ColorName);
            const isActiveChecked = isActive ? true : false;
            $('#isActive').prop('checked',isActiveChecked);
            $('#TheModal').modal('show');
        });


//The Select statement in the form on the modal
<cfoutput>
<select name="ColorID" class="frmcontrol" placeholder="Car Color">
   <option value="" Selected>--- Select ---</option>
   <cfloop query="GetColors">
      <option value="#ColorID#">#ColorName#</option>
   </cfloop>    
</select>
</cfoutput>


<cfloop> is not HTML, it's ColdFusion.

From what you’ve posted, it’s hard to tell what you’ll need to do. Assuming you have a list of vehicles in a datatable, you’ll want to open the modal when the user clicks on a vehicle. Then when the modal is open, you’re going to want to backfill the form with the details of the vehicle so you can edit it. Usually I do that by making another ajax call to the backend to get the data in json format, which makes it easy to backfill the form.

I need the fields value of the Select element to be selected when the edit functionality comes up.  The same as if you weren't using jQuery and with just using Coldfusion & SQL or any other programming language. Just like the Input Text Element for Car Name would be.

The code you posted doesn’t provide enough information to indicate how to do what you want. Also, you are using JavaScript and jquery so it’s also not clear why you can’t refactor your code to do it differently. If you are doing it only with coldfusion and you want your html output to backfill your form in the modal dialog, you would need to output the html for the modal/form with the values of the vehicle data, but you are not showing any of that code.

Yeah, there is a whole lot of code I'm not showing because it confuses people. It looks like I put too much code in there anyway. Keep it simple. Here goes: How would you loop over the items in the drop down, compare them to the choice already selected in the record, and have that one selected?

Is #ColorID# in your edit icon the pre-selected color? If so, while you are looping over your color dictionary to create your options, check the option against the pre-selected color: <cfset optionSelected = (getColors.colorID eq variables.ColorID) ? "selected" : ""><option value="#ColorID#" #optionSelected#>#ColorName#</option>

We can't do it it within Coldfusion because of the DOM. I'm a Coldfusion Developer. Which is why I'm writing this question. I don't know how to do it in jQuery & Data Tables. The data comes from SQL, through a CFC (access="remote" returnformat="json" returntype="struct") , & is stored in that button (the first line of the code shown).

I'm not making the connection between the DataTables and the select element... You asked How do I have the vehicle color that is already saved, pre-Selected in the form element in the modal?

Yes, that's how I would say it. I apologize for my wording and not using the right lingo. So I'll use an example instead: Think of an account you have online somewhere, anywhere, and you go edit your profile on your account. On your account you go to the section for language and click edit. English is already selected in the drop down. Got it?  I chose that example because it has to be in a Select element drop down as opposed to an Input = Text element.

Somebody told me something about "Each" for some kind of jQuery loop and it has to equal the value selected. Heck, if I wasn't using Data Tables for every Admin area on the site I would just do everything in Coldfusion, but that's what the boss man wants so therefore that's how it shall be.

It's not really about lingo, here. I just don't see any actual references to a table that would make DataTables relevant here.  Have you attempted to use my suggestion in your getColors loop? Your question seems to refer to selecting a particular option in your select element, and I've used this particular method all the time.

I got help at work to figure it out. This is all the jQuery I needed.
$('#ColorID > option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == ColorID) {
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
  }
});

